# How to write a dispatch function which can only access from offchain worker with signed extrinsic/transaction?

Tags: storage, extrinsic, offchain-worker

I want to modify some on-chain storage from offchain worker by sending a signed transaction, so I write a dispatch function which handles the transaction. But the dispatch function also can be accessed from other way as normal（such as a user sign an extrinsic out of blockchain）. I want to block the other ways so the on-chain storage only can be modified by offchain worker. How to do this, or is there any method that can distinguish different access path？

Or how can I extract the `KeyTypeId` from `AccountId`?

Comment: why not just check the origin of the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The `pallet::call` macro requires the function to be public. So it's either in the frontend you just don't expose the function but anyhow a user can access the function (using polkadot js to interact with your chain).

Because even the ofchain worker requires the Call to be public.